# Tkinter GUI search stock ticker from image file names in folder with text box and display image

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a Tkinter GUI to search for stock ticker name in search box, with OK button, which then searches for the ticker in the filenames within a folder of stock chart image files, and then displays the image. Here is what I have tried so far, unfortunately, the search box doesn't do anything and I am stuck. The filename is currently hardcoded but you'll notice the `S6COND` in `file="./charts/sample_regression_S6COND.png"`. That would be the ticker symbol. The charts folder is full of these files named by the stock ticker. How could I have the GUI search for an image file in the folder by these ticker symbols? Thank you.

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("1100x700")
window.title('CAPE')


def func(event):
    img_label = tk.Label(window)
    img_label.image = tk.PhotoImage(file="./charts/sample_regression_S6COND.png")
    img_label['image'] = img_label.image
    img_label.pack()


def onclick(event):
    img_label = tk.Label(window)
    img_label.image = tk.PhotoImage(file="./charts/sample_regression_S6COND.png")
    img_label['image'] = img_label.image
    img_label.pack()


ticker = tk.StringVar()

search = tk.Frame(window)
search.pack(padx=10, pady=10, fill='x', expand=True)
search_label = tk.Label(window, text="Ticker")
search_label.pack(fill='x', expand=True)
search_entry = tk.Entry(window)
search_entry.pack(fill='x', expand=True)
search_entry.focus()

window.bind('<Return>', func)

button = tk.Button(window, text="OK")
button.bind('<Button-1>', onclick)
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

sadly,tkinter does not support realtime lookup apart from looping this code every time a new letter gets inputted, but after pressing ok, you can slap this code in to search.

```
import os

def find(name, path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        if name in files:
            return os.path.join(root, name)
```

then you can return a label text which can be either true or false, or display filename as seen in the code here.
(os.walk is very useful and should be common practice for conservative beginning os developers. Not only does it look through generic filepaths (and with your case you can just specify path + query). While not being the most efficient os tools provide a great foundation for learning filescanning in python.